# Creating a scoring system PHP

Tags: php, substr, scoring

I am in the middle of creating a scoring system for a questionnaire based application and I am currently trying to do the following:

```
select all questions from the table
```

while (fetch the next question) {
    remove the first character from the answer string and use as the score
    get the factorCode and invertCode from the question just read

```
add the score to each factor affected
```

}

So far i have the following but I cant understand what the while condition will be

```
<?php
$dbQuery = $db->prepare("select text from questions");
$dbQuery->execute();
while()
{
    //declare factor scores & maxFactors array 15 elements fill with 0's
    $maxFactors=array("0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0");
    $factorScores=array("0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0");



    //-----
    // get $response from answers use substring
    $response= substr($str, 1);

    // get $factorCode from database
    $dbQuery = $db->prepare("select FactorCode from questions");
        $dbQuery->execute();

        while ($dbRow = $dbQuery->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $FactorCode = $dbRow['FactorCode'];

    for ($thisFactor=15; $thisFactor>=6; $thisFactor--)
    {   $value=2^($thisFactor-1)

        if $thisFactor>=$value{
            invert $factorScores[$thisFactor]+=$response;
            //invert $factorScores[$thisFactor]+=(6-$response);
            $maxFactors[$thisFactor]+=5; 
            $factorCode-=$value;
        }   
    }
}
//-------
//print 2 arrays
print_r($maxFactors);
print_r ($factorScores);
```

?>

Comment: I am not sure but maybe the while condition should be iteration through the result of the select statement at the top. http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php

Comment: Also, where is the value of `$str` coming from in your code ?

Comment: There is an $answers variable in my code above this php that is a string of numbers but I only want the first number from the string removed and stored as a score each time.

Comment: You might want to edit your question to include that part also then.

Answer (score 0):

Well if your question is how to run trough all the different responses, then

```
while ($dbQuery->fetchInto($row))
```

To select your data, $row[0] = first col $row[1] second col and so on

In order not to break your code you might wanna start using different variables for everything, now it's all dbQuery and that's pretty bad. Once the inside of the while is executed the while will break, so rename the variables from the second query if you want to run it for every row of the first query.